# Application.exit on text file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a windows forms application.

I have to put application.exit in Load.

But when needed buttons on the forms should be used.
I think I should call app.exit from another file like txt or something.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintTheDocument();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    textBox1.Text = GetDefaultPrinterName().ToString();
    Application.Exit();
}
```

How can I modify

```
Application.Exit();
```

From outside of code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintTheDocument();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    textBox1.Text = GetDefaultPrinterName().ToString();
    //Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: your grammer is very pretty bad , i dont understand what u are saying

Comment: So you say "when needed", what does that mean? What's the condition?

Comment: Why do you want to close the application when a form is loaded? This doesn't make sense - why even start loading the form when it gets never shown because the application has closed already? What do you actually want to do?

Comment: "I have to put application.exit in Load." - could you explain the reasons? It is a very curious requirement.

Comment: it's an application for printing.
it just print the desinged label, inside of an another application.
i solved the problem BTW. I created a text file in the path and if that text contains 'YES', it returns the form, otherwise it runs application.exit . Thanks for all comments. The reason i'm doing this, because in the form there is a 'design the label' button, so if the customer wants to change it's label, he will change the design by himself